# Difference between Auditing vs Diagnostic settings in SQL Azure

Tags: azure

In SQL Azure, there are two options for getting database events in Azure portal are **Auditing** and **Diagnostic settings**.

In which scenario we will use them.

Comment: auditing vs diagnostics, they do not mean the same thing, right?

Comment: Correct.. I am trying to understand whats the difference in azure perspective..

Answer (score 2):

**Azure SQL database Auditing** is usually used for:

- **Retain** an audit trail of selected events. You can define categories
  of database actions to be audited.
- **Report** on database activity. You can use pre-configured reports and a
  dashboard to get started quickly with activity and event reporting.
- **Analyze** reports. You can find suspicious events, unusual activity,
  and trends.

**Diagnostics settings**:

You can use the Diagnostics settings menu for each single, pooled, or instance database in Azure portal to configure streaming of diagnostics telemetry. In addition, diagnostic telemetry can also be configured separately for database containers: elastic pools and managed instances. You can set the following destinations to stream the diagnostics telemetry: Azure Storage, Azure Event Hubs, and Azure Monitor logs.

As 4c74356b41 said, they are difference things and with different uses.

Please reference:

1. [Azure SQL Database metrics and diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-metrics-diag-logging)
2. [Get started with SQL database auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ManasKumar You're welcome. If my answer is helpful for you, can you please accept it(mark) as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this "When auditing is configured to a Log Analytics workspace or to an Event Hub destination via the Azure portal or PowerShell cmdlet, a Diagnostic Setting is created with "SQLSecurityAuditEvents" category enabled.".
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview)

For me, this means that auditing is an easier way to enable one of the features of Diagnostic Settings.